# apex parse csv that contains double quote in every single records

Tags: string, csv, salesforce, apex, double-quotes

```
public static List<List<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {
List<List<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();

// replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma
// in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote
// do this for beginning and end of a field
contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');
// now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct
// fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote
contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');
// we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them
// so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows
List<String> lines = new List<String>();
try {
    lines = contents.split('\n');
} catch (System.ListException e) {
    System.debug('Limits exceeded?' + e.getMessage());
}
Integer num = 0;
for(String line : lines) {
    // check for blank CSV lines (only commas)
    if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;

    List<String> fields = line.split(',');  
    List<String> cleanFields = new List<String>();
    String compositeField;
    Boolean makeCompositeField = false;
    for(String field : fields) {
        if (field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
            cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
        } else if (field.startsWith('"')) {
            makeCompositeField = true;
            compositeField = field;
        } else if (field.endsWith('"')) {
            compositeField += ',' + field;
            cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
            makeCompositeField = false;
        } else if (makeCompositeField) {
            compositeField +=  ',' + field;
        } else {
            cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
        }
    }

    allFields.add(cleanFields);

}


if(skipHeaders)allFields.remove(0);

return allFields;       
}
```

I use this part to parse CSV file, but i find out i cant parse when the CSV are all bounded by double quotes.

For example, i have records like these
"a","b","c","d,e,f","g"

After parsing, i would like to get these
a    b    c    d,e,f     g

Comment: d,e,f  should be put un one record

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seen, the first thing you do is to split the line you get from the CSV file by commas, using this line:

> List < String > fields = line.split(',');

When you do this to your own example ("a","b","c","d,e,f","g"), what you get as your list of string is:

> fields = ("a" | "b" | "c" | **"d** | **e** | **f"** | "g"), where the bar is used to separate the list elements

The issue here is that, if you first split by commas, it will be a little more difficult to differentiate those commas that are part of a field (because they actually appeared inside quotes), from those that separate fields in you CSV.

I suggest trying do split the line by quotes, which would give you something like this:

> fields = (a | , | b | , | c | , | d, e, f | , | g)

and filter out any elements of you list that are only commas and/or spaces, finally achieving this:

> fields = (a | b | c | d, e, f | g)

---

**(edited)**

Is that Java you're using?
Anyways, here is a Java code that does what you're trying to do:

```
import java.lang.*;

import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allFields = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    // separating the file in lines
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\n"));

    // ignoring header, if needed
    if(skipHeaders) lines.remove(0);

    // for each line
    for(String line : lines) {
        List<String> fields = Arrays.asList(line.split("\""));  
        ArrayList<String> cleanFields = new ArrayList<String>();
        Boolean isComma = false; 
        for(String field : fields) {
          // ignore elements that don't have useful data
          // (every other element after splitting by quotes)
          isComma = !isComma;
          if (isComma) continue;

          cleanFields.add(field);
        }

        allFields.add(cleanFields);
    }

    return allFields;       
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // example of input file:
    // Line 1: "a","b","c","d,e,f","g"
    // Line 2: "a1","b1","c1","d1,e1,f1","g1"
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> strings = HelloWorld.parseCSV("\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d,e,f\",\"g\"\n\"a1\",\"b1\",\"c1\",\"d1,e1,f1\",\"g1\"",false);
    System.out.println("Result:");
    for (ArrayList<String> list : strings) {
      System.out.println("  New List:");
      for (String str : list) {
        System.out.println("    - " + str);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i remove the double quote in a string?  it seems that the code is not working.

Comment: field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"')